# Application is slow on domain which connect application through AJP Connector

Tags: apache, jboss, subdomain, mod-jk

My application is deployed on port 8080 on JBoss 6. I used Apache as Web Server on 80 port and connected to JBoss application server by MOD_JK. 
When i open application with public URL on 8080, speed is Okey.
But When i open through domain then speed is very slow as it connect to JBoss server through AJP Connector.

What can i do to get speed as with public URL.
Can i discard Apache and directly run jboss 80.

Comment: When you say "through domain" do you mean you are running JBoss6 in domain mode (not standalone mode) or do you mean something else?

Comment: when i open www.xyz.com then it is slow. But when i open like 50.50.50.50:8080/apps/, it is ok.
I make call to my application using apache mok_jk connector.

Comment: And do you see this slowness just with a single request (not when load testing and not when lots of other users are using the system) ?